# How to invalidate the usage of a OpenVpn client without revoke it in the CA Server?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I created a VPN Server following the Digital Ocean tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-22-04) and I created a lot of client certs (and .ovpn files) to connect on it.

Now, I would like to revoke many of these certs, but using the suggested process (revoke it on the CA, and copy the .pem file to VPN server) is like to work with a black list (every cert is allowed, instead those is included on .pem).

I'd like to manage the access in a while list model (no one has access, instead of those registered in somewhere). Is there some way to make it ?

I tried exclude the users .crt files on the VPN server and restart the openvpn service, but the certs continues working after that.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/55648/openvpn-certificate-whitelist-instead-of-crl